# jpa namedquery with literals changed to prepared statement

Tags: jpa, prepared-statement, openjpa, named-query, sqlperformance

I have a jpa (openjpa-2.2.1) namedquery that has some hardcoded literals (ex: a.status <> 'X') - the problem is at runtime the generated query is actually a prepared statement (a.status <> ?)

**Is there a way to force JPA run the query as is?** (i would like to keep it as namedquery, not implement it as native query or other ways)

I would like to run the query as is because of performance reasons - the static query runs in a db client in about 2 seconds while the prepared statement fired from JUNIT in 3-4 mins. (we had performance problems in the past with prepared statements for some queries and changing to static queries did the trick)

Comment: Can you post some code? Named queries that cause the problem, the code which calls them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the query hint `openjpa.hint.UseLiteralInSQL=true` ([ref](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/openjpa/kernel/QueryHints.html#HINT_USE_LITERAL_IN_SQL)). See [this IBM technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM81062) for more details.

Comment: Exactly the answer i was looking for. Thanks. One more thing - for some reason the hint seems to be ignored and the query is still generated as prepared statement - any idea what else do i need to do to get the hint working?

Comment: I believe that OpenJPA will always create a PreparedStatement. This property is supposed to make the runtime generate literals in that statement rather than convert to params.

Comment: Ok, but this is the problem - i still see params - not literals

Comment: Are you certain that you are using the query hint properly?

Comment: Query q = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("namedQuery");  
q.setHint("openjpa.hint.UseLiteralInSQL", true); <tried "true" as string also>  
q.getResultList());  
  
Also tried declarative way:  
hints={ @QueryHint  (name="openjpa.hint.UseLiteralInSQL", value="true")} )

Comment: Perhaps the version of OpenJPA you are running doesn't support that hint? I don't have source code on this machine, otherwise I'd check for you.